# Converting vertex normals to face normals

Tags: geometry

I have a triangulated 3D polyhedron (not necessarily convex) and the following information:

A list of the position of each vertex. A list of the vertex triples that define each face. A list of the vertex normals (Here the vertex normals are vectors from each vertex that are calculated by averaging face normals (see below) around each vertex).

I would like to calculate the list of face normals (The normalized vectors perpendicular to the plane of each face, pointing outward).

Answer (score 0):

For each face, to get the normal, average the unique set of three *vertex* normals bordering that face.